# How to append elements from a list into nested lists in a dataframe one by one

Tags: python, list, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [[[1,2],[2,3]],[[3,4],[2,5]],[[5,6],[5,6],[5,6]],[7,8]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

C = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

I have a pandas dataframe and would like to append each element of a C list into each one of the nested lists of B, maintaining the structure, so that the resulting dataframe is:

```
'A': [1,2,3,4]
'B': [[[1,2,1],[2,3,2]],[[3,4,3],[2,5,4]],[[5,6,5],[5,6,6],[5,6,7]],[7,8,8]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mybe there is a more elegant solution, but this works :-)

```
for i in d['B']:
    for j in i:
        if (isinstance(j, list)):
            j.append(C.pop(0))
        else:
            i.append(C.pop(0))
            break
```

A more efficient solution based on timgebs comment (thank you!):

```
f = iter(C)
for i in d['B']:
    for j in i:
        if (isinstance(j, list)):
            j.append(next(f))
        else:
            i.append(next(f))
            break
```

Comment: Consider getting the `next` element from a listiterator over `C`, this way you won't have to perform the O(n) `pop` operation in each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative method using `itertools`.

The idea is to flatten the list of lists, append your data, then split again via information you have stored on the number of lists in each row.

```
from itertools import chain, accumulate
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [[[1,2],[2,3]],[[3,4],[2,5]],[[5,6],[5,6],[5,6]],[[7,8]]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
C = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

acc = [0] + list(accumulate(map(len, B)))

lst = [j+[C[i]] for i, j in enumerate(chain.from_iterable(df['B']))]

df['B'] = [lst[x:y] for x, y in zip(acc, acc[1:])]
```

Note I have made an important change to the input: the last element of series `B` is a list of lists, just like all the other elements. For consistency, I would recommend this in any case.

**Result**

```
   A                                  B
0  1             [[1, 2, 1], [2, 3, 2]]
1  2             [[3, 4, 3], [2, 5, 4]]
2  3  [[5, 6, 5], [5, 6, 6], [5, 6, 7]]
3  4                        [[7, 8, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [[[1,2],[2,3]],[[3,4],[2,5]],[[5,6],[5,6],[5,6]],[7,8]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

C = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

df['B_len'] = df.B.apply(len)
df['B_len_cumsum']=df.B_len.cumsum()
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: C[row['B_len_cumsum']-row['B_len']:row['B_len_cumsum']], axis=1)
df['B'] = df.B.apply(lambda x: [x] if type(x[0])==int else x)
for x,y in zip(df.B,df.C):
        for xx,yy in zip(x,y):
            xx.append(yy)
df
```

Output:

```
   A                                  B  B_len  B_len_cumsum          C
0  1             [[1, 2, 1], [2, 3, 2]]      2             2     [1, 2]
1  2             [[3, 4, 3], [2, 5, 4]]      2             4     [3, 4]
2  3  [[5, 6, 5], [5, 6, 6], [5, 6, 7]]      3             7  [5, 6, 7]
3  4                        [[7, 8, 8]]      2             9        [8]
```